# How to use many to many relationship in NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two entities Group and Contact. A contact can belong to many groups, and a group have many contacts. So I create many to many relationship. like this:

```
Group           Contact
attribute       attribute
  gname           name
  gid             gender
relationship    relationship
  cnt<<--------->>grp
```

I want to display all contacts in a UITableView, which have many sections, each section have many rows. like this:

```
GroupA
  Contact1
  Contact2
  Contact3
GroupB
  Contact1
  Contact3
GroupC
  Contact2
  Contact3
```

My question is how to create the NSFetchedResultsController to achieve this? I can use attribute to divide UITableView into sections. I have tried to divide it use a simple to many relationship, but failed, as for many to many, I...

If I have a group named "GroupD", which have no contact belong to. So Contact entity don't have any row whose grp attribute contain "GroupD", Then I got only three sections. I want my UITableView to be like this:

```
GroupA
  Contact1
  Contact2
  Contact3
GroupB
  Contact1
  Contact3
GroupC
  Contact2
  Contact3
GroupD
```

but I did got:

```
GroupA
  Contact1
  Contact2
  Contact3
GroupB
  Contact1
  Contact3
GroupC
  Contact2
  Contact3
```

I think the biggest problem is my way of create NSFetchedResultsController.

please help.

any reply will be appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think it's not possible for UITableView to show section without cells. If you can accept that fact, then your NSFetchResultController should be like below.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = ....
NSEntityDescription *entity = .... @"Contact" ....
fetchRequest.entity = entity;

[NSFetchResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                   ...
                                   sectionNameKeyPath:@"grp"
                                   ...
```